# Google Spreadsheet Version of COUNTIFS statement

Tags: excel-formula, google-docs

I need to convert the formula below to a googledoc available formula.  I've had trouble doing this with array formulas.

=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!J:J,"M",Sheet1!K:K,"Yes")

Answer (score -1):

This?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(A2:A13,"m")+COUNTIF(B2:B13,"yes"))/2
```

Divide by the total columns you are searching...